# Python/pandas/os: get the files in this folder and iterate over those that fit this naming convention

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

I want to perform some data cleaning on all the files in the same folder as my script that fit a naming convention.

The data cleaning I am fine with, but it's just the same folder that I am struggling with.

Previous working code:

```
import glob 
for filename in glob.glob('C:/Users/<me>/Downloads/New Folder/Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx'):
```

Current code:

```
import os
for filename in os.getcwd() + '\Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx':
```

I get the error code

`No such file or directory: 'C'`

Do I need to do some kind of replacement to turn the \s into /s? As the code suggests, I want all files that start with 'Forecast and Inventory'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through a string.

Since `os.getcwd() + '\Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx'` is the string `"C://**working-dir/Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx"`

So on the first iteration `filename` is the string `'C'`.

For example

```
for filename in os.getcwd() + '\Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx':
    print(filename)
```

WIll return

```
"C"
":"
"/"
...
```

You just need to put the path inside `glob.glob`

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '\Forecast and Inventory *.xlsx'):
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry it was such a basic question!!